# VBA Code Copy Paste Multiple Cells if Condition is Met

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm seeking assistance with copying and pasting specific cells that meet a requirement from my source data sheet to a "dashboard" sheet. I have the code below but when I run the macro it only copy and pastes the last row that meets the criteria, not all rows that meet the criteria.

For reference, I am copying 3 cells from a row in a table on the source data sheet, that may increase or decrease in size any given day, and pasting the 3 cells to the bottom of a different table in the dashboard sheet.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim SourceData As Worksheet
Dim Dashboard As Worksheet

Dim searchString As String

Dim lastSourceRow As Long
Dim startSourceRow As Long
Dim lastTargetRow As Long
Dim sourceRowCounter As Long
Dim columnToEval As Long
Dim columnCounter As Long

Dim columnsToCopy As Variant
Dim columnsDestination As Variant


Set SourceData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source Data")
Set Dashboard = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")


columnsToCopy = Array(7, 8, 11)
columnsDestination = Array(2, 3, 4)


searchString = "New"


startSourceRow = 3


columnToEval = 45


lastSourceRow = SourceData.Cells(SourceData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For sourceRowCounter = startSourceRow To lastSourceRow

        If SourceData.Cells(sourceRowCounter, columnToEval).Value = searchString Then

          
            lastTargetRow = Dashboard.Cells(Dashboard.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            For columnCounter = 0 To UBound(columnsToCopy)

              
                Dashboard.Cells(lastTargetRow, columnsDestination(columnCounter)).Offset(1, 0).Value = SourceData.Cells(sourceRowCounter, columnsToCopy(columnCounter)).Value

            Next columnCounter

        End If

Next sourceRowCounter


SourceData.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: You're populating columns 2,3 and 4 but getting `lastTargetRow` from column 1

Comment: @TimWilliams that's correct. I'm using lastTargetRow to run through all the values in column 1 and get the last row on the target sheet. Then using columnsDestination to paste to columns 2,3 and 4 after that last row. My problem is when I have multiple rows in my source data that meet my search string criteria, it isn't copying and pasting all of them. It just grabs the last instance that meets my criteria on my source sheet and pastes it to my target sheet.

Comment: No, it just pastes all of the rows on top of each other, because populating columns  2-4 does not change the position of the last value in Col A. That's why it seems like only the last row was copied.  One approach would be to get the value of `lastTargetRow` before you enter the search loop, then increment it by 1 for each copied row.

Answer (score 0):

Following from comments above:

```vb
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim SourceData As Worksheet
    Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
    Dim searchString As String
    Dim lastSourceRow As Long
    Dim startSourceRow As Long
    Dim lastTargetRow As Long
    Dim sourceRowCounter As Long
    Dim columnToEval As Long
    Dim columnCounter As Long
    Dim columnsToCopy As Variant
    Dim columnsDestination As Variant
    
    Set SourceData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source Data")
    Set Dashboard = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
    
    columnsToCopy = Array(7, 8, 11)
    columnsDestination = Array(2, 3, 4)
    
    searchString = "New"
    startSourceRow = 3
    columnToEval = 45
    
    lastTargetRow = Dashboard.Cells(Dashboard.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'move this out of the loop
    lastSourceRow = SourceData.Cells(SourceData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For sourceRowCounter = startSourceRow To lastSourceRow
        If SourceData.Cells(sourceRowCounter, columnToEval).Value = searchString Then
            
            For columnCounter = 0 To UBound(columnsToCopy)
                Dashboard.Cells(lastTargetRow, columnsDestination(columnCounter)).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
                      SourceData.Cells(sourceRowCounter, columnsToCopy(columnCounter)).Value
            Next columnCounter
            lastTargetRow = lastTargetRow + 1 'next destination row
        End If
    Next sourceRowCounter
    
    SourceData.Activate

End Sub
```